# GnuPG passphrase entry and X11 sniffing

Tags: key-management, gnupg, keyloggers, passphrase, x11

Each time when I’m entering my passphrase in `pinentry-gtk-2`, every other X11 app may sniff it, as seen in

```
$ xinput test-xi2
```

running in the background.

What can be done about it?

Or do I have to trust hundreds of different processes running under my account<sup>(*)</sup> to **not** X11-sniff my passphrase when I’m typing it and **not** send my `~/.gnupg/` directory along with it over the internet to some adversary?

<sup>(*)</sup> Here, I’m not considering an almost-hardware keylogger running as `root` very close to the kernel, as not much can be done about that. I’m talking regular, user-land applications, like closed-source [Skype](https://www.skype.com/) or [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/).

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to run your session as SELinux user `user_u` or `staff_u`, which will much more strictly enforce inter-process communication between other apps and the pin entry app, which runs in `gpg_pinentry_t` domain.

By default, users are mapped to `unconfined_u`, which offers *some* protection, but not nearly as much as if you were to run things as `user_u` (e.g. you will notice that most things run as `unconfined_t`, but firefox plugins are executed as `mozilla_plugin_t`).

For extra high paranoia, you can try [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) which solves precisely this problem -- but it requires getting used to the constraints it imposes on your work environment.

Comment: Maybe it should be added that SELinux is not available in most Linux distros but confined to Red Hat, Fedora, CentOS and friends on the desktop.